# Flex reverse proxy issues

Tags: apache-flex, flash, apache, proxy

I'm currently working on setting up a reverse proxy for testing a flex-based web application.

The current setup is using mod`_`proxy (with mod`_`proxy`_`http) to reverse proxy to another host.  Everything seems to work except for requests made from the flash player, which result in an error message that says "Security error accessing url".

I have a crossdomain.xml set up on the back end system that simply allows everything, using "<allow-access-from domain="*"/>".

The crossdomain.xml is available off of / from both the backend and proxy server.

The odd part is that when I monitor the connection traffic with firebug, the browser is bypassing the proxy and going straight to the backend server to get the crossdomain.xml file.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get the flex behave properly in an environment like this?

I have included my proxy configuration below.

`<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

        ProxyRequests Off`

```
    <Proxy *>
            AddDefaultCharset off
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    # Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
    # ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
    # Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block

    ProxyVia On

<Location "/">
    ProxyPass http://backend:9080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://backend:9080/
</Location>
```

</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually the result of the endpoints written in the WSDLs that were generated by the web application.  They contained the URL of the backend server.  I had to turn on the "ProxyPreserveHost" directive to get it to use the proxy's url for the endpoints.  That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The flash player needs to be given the URL to the reverse proxy server, not the flex server.