# Flex web services and reverse proxy

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, wsdl, reverse-proxy

I have a similar problem to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324594/flex-reverse-proxy-issues) and I found the answer here to be helpful but I have a few more questions.

I've setup my project using Flash Builder 4 and imported my WSDL using the web service wizard making sure I pointed to the WSDL on the proxy. However simply doing that and enabling the "ProxyPreserveHost" directive did not allow the web services to run from the application being run on the proxy server. They just hang with no error or response.

So in addition to this I added this line of code to the service class that the Flash Builder wizard created:

```
_serviceControl.endpointURI = "https://site.mycompany.com/MyService/MyService";
```

This fixed the problem but I'm not sure as to why this is a problem in the first place.  The location in the WSDL is specified to be http://site.mycompany.com:80/MyService/MyService and the server should be processing that request and converting it to https.

Anyone have any ideas or examples of how to get a Flex app built in Flash Builder working with a reverse proxy in place?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for referencing a previous question; and actually doing some research before posting.

Comment: Does the WSDL specify the endpoint URI to one that wouldn't work from the environment you're testing?  If so, then that's why you have to specify the right one.  Specifically look for this tag in the WSDL (example):

<service name="AmazonSearchService">
<!-- Endpoint for Amazon Web APIs -->
<port name="AmazonSearchPort" binding="typens:AmazonSearchBinding">
<soap:address location="http://soap.amazon.com/onca/soap2"/>
</port>
</service>

What does "location=" point to?